# You don't have permission to access /test2/ on this server

Tags: objective-c, ftp, connection

I have provided with accurate ftp username and password
But i am unable to connect with the server.

I am coding on objective c.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ftp resources directly. You will require FTP client for that.
Find some good FTP library for objective c which fulfills your requirement.
Try https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager may be it help.